# How can I bind a key to cycle through panes?

Tags: shortcut-keys, tmux

I've got a few tmux key bindings like this, which allow me to switch windows without using the mouse

```
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L    ## move left one pane
```

How can I bind a single key that can cycle through the panes on the screen (similar to how <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> works)?

Comment: Like a single key for ALT+TAB?

Comment: yes, exactly. let me update the question to clarify.

Comment: I edited your question to use <kbd> tags for ALT+TAB

Answer (score 3):

With default keybindings:

```
Ctrl+b n
```

will flip thru to the next window, same way alt-tab works for windowed applications.

```
Ctrl+b o
```

Should flip through the panes within the window.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you could use `bind-key -n M-Up next-window` to cycle through windows, 1 at a time by pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>CursorUp</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CursorUp</kbd> on most systems).